# Avoid pen tool from modifying another path in After Effects CC?

Tags: pen-tool, adobe-after-effects

Sometimes when drawing a path using the Pen Tool in After Effects when I want to click in a place that is near another path a plus sign appears to the pen and modifies that path if I click.

How can I stop that?

Here is a screenshot of what I mean:

[image]

Thank you all!

Oscar.

Comment: Can you lock or hide paths in AE? That's how you overcome this in Illustrator. (I just don't know AE.)

Answer (score 1):

Try using the direct selection to select nothing then switch back to the pen tool, I've used this technique in multiple Adobe Software, it's strange!

Comment: Mind adding some more clarification? An image or two would explain what you're trying to say more clearly. Welcome to GD!